# If statement is true but code doesn't execute C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
public bool CheckTheEmail(string email)
    {
        //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("insQuoteConnectionString"))
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["insQuoteConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmailAddress from AspNetUsers", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //do something


                           if (reader[0] != null)
                            {
                                if (reader[0] == (email))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("ok");
                                    reader.Close();
                                    con.Close();
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            con.Close();

        }
        return false;
    }
```

this statement if (reader[0] == (email)) shows true but doesn't execute the code!

The if statement returns true (shown in screen shot) but doesn't execute.

[image]

Comment: doest not print "ok" also?

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the error, what does/doesn't execute, etc.?

Comment: Did you recently modify that line?  If you somehow restart a debugging session without rebuilding, it can trace through your current code in the editor, but may actually be executing different code in the debugger.  Do a Clean / Rebuild to double-check

Comment: Did you ever enter the `while` loop? (`reader.Read()` returned false on the first call)

Comment: Can you provide any more information? I can't see any reason why you're experiencing the described behavior. What Type is the `email` variable? Is this code surrounded by a `try` block? Where does the code jump to instead of executing the block after `if`?

Comment: Try setting a break point on `if (reader[0] == (email))`. What happens when you step into the code?

Comment: It goes inside the while loop no problem - It then declares (reader[0] == (email)) true - but fails to execute the code in its { }. Everything works fine except that the code in the if statement is not being executed despite it being declared true...

Comment: I set a break point and took the screen shot.

Comment: Are you running this method asynchronously? In another thread? We really need more context behind your code.

Comment: Are you compiling with or without JIT optimization? In other words, does the same thing happen for both Debug and Release?

Comment: An email is entered into a text box, upon a button click this code is fired. all if statements work correctly but the "if (reader[0] == (email))" doesn't execute. even though true... I have updated the code above to show more...

Comment: FYI your using statements will take care of calling `Close()`, so you can take those calls out

Comment: Is `email` a text box control?  Also what are you using to verify that `reader[0] == (email)`

Comment: Place an `else` block with `Console.WriteLine("not ok")`, and see if that executes while the `if` block is "true"

Comment: Are there any circumstances that an if statement won't fire despite being declared true? I replaced  'reader[0] == (email)' with 'true' and it fired.

Comment: @GlenCloake Sure, when the debugger lies to you about it. Try this and see if it's still weird: `if (reader[0].ToString() == email)`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're comparing something, it's good practice to make sure they're of compatible types. In this case, `SqlDataReader` is actually returning an `Object`, so you need to cast it into a `string` before doing the comparison. (I'm actually surprised IntelliSense didn't complain about it)

```
public bool CheckTheEmail(string email)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["insQuoteConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmailAddress from AspNetUsers", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader == default(SqlDataReader))
            {
                return false;
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //do something

                if (reader[0] != null && reader[0].ToString() == email)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ok");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```